# Python having the "self.attrs[key]]" error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, keyerror

I'm starting to learn code some complex things on python and today I decided to work with BeautifulSoup. The problem appear when I tried to get the title of a product, I attempt to change ".find" to ".findAll" and can't find the solution. Someone please help me.
Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
ListaSteam = "https://store.steampowered.com/search/?sort_by=Price_ASC&category1=998%2C996&category2=29"

#PAGINA - OBTENCION - CERRADA
Pagina = uReq(ListaSteam)
PaginaHtml = Pagina.read()
Pagina.close()

#1 PASO
PaginaSoup = Soup(PaginaHtml, "html.parser")
CodigoJuegos = PaginaSoup.find("div",{"id":"search_resultsRows"})
PRUEBA = CodigoJuegos.a.span["title"]
print(PRUEBA)
```

The error is as follows:

```
This is the error:
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\******", line 14, in <module>
    PRUEBA = CodigoJuegos.a.span["title"]
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1406, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'title'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you should use [PEP8 styling](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It is hard to read your code.

If you want to solve it with the least amount of code change do the following:

```
PRUEBA = CodigoJuegos.a.span.text
```

That said, I scrape websites professionally using (among other tools bs4), and I'd go for something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

search_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/search"
category1 = ('998', '996')
category2 = '29'

params = {
    'sort_by': 'Price_ASC',
    'category1': ','.join(category1),
    'category2': category2,
}

response = requests.get(
    search_url,
    params=params
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
elms = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "title"})

for elm in elms: 
    print(elm.text)
```

Output:

```
Barro F
The Last Hope: Trump vs Mafia - North Korea
Ninja Stealth
Tetropunk
Oracle
Legend of Himari
Planes, Bullets and Vodka
Shift
Blast-off
...
```

If you already have a dependency to `bs4`, you might as well also get `requests` too.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to do:

```
PRUEBA = CodigoJuegos.a.get_text("title")
```

Answer (score 0):

using css selector `'spna.title'`

```
CodigoJuegos = PaginaSoup.select('span.title')
for t in CodigoJuegos:
    print(t.text)
```